# Ajax refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ajax

On change of dropdown im reading the drop down value and making on ajax call to fetch the data.I want to refresh the same page.
i tried this

```
$('#status').change(function(){

    var status = $('#status').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "Partners.action",
        data: {status : status},
        success : function(data) {
            alert(status);
            $("#status").html(data);

        }
    });
});
```

but it is not refreshing

Comment: what do you mean by refreshing? The complete page refresh?

Comment: What do you need to be refreshed?. As i can see you are updating the  status input with the response.

Comment: `$('#status')` why are you updating the html of it in success function.

Comment: Refreshing a page kinda defeats the purpose of AJAX

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#status').change(function(){

    var status = $('#status').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "Partners.action",
        data: {status : status},
        success : function(data) {
            alert(status);
            $("#status").html(data);
           window.location="currentPageURL.aspx?data="+data; /// for refreshing the page

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i want to refresh the entire page with data i got from ajax call, and also the action i am hitting returning the same jsp

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You can do the page refresh using the method proposed by @Neel.
But In case you want to refresh the whole page and get the data back, you first need to store it in some database.

Also, you are filling the data in the same control on which you are observing the `.change` event.

Replace `$("#status").html(data);` with `$('#YourHTMLControl').html(data);`

**Alternate Method:**
Another way of doing it would be the use of querystring.
You can do it something like this.

```
success : function(data) {
    alert(status);
    $("#status").html(data);
    window.location="currentPageURL.aspx?data="+data;
}
```

Later you can read the querystring on page load and insert it into the desired control using javascript or any server side method.

Hope it helps.